# Replace commas enclosed in curly braces (but not quite)

Tags: regex

This seems to be a duplicate question of an already asked one but not really. What I'm looking for is one or more regular expressions without the help of any programming language to change the following text `String.Concat( new string[] { "some", "random", "text", string1, string2, "end" })` into `"some" + "random" + "text" + string1 + string2 + "end"`.

I was thinking of using two regular expressions, replacing the commas with pluses, and then removing the `String.Concat( new string[] { ... })`. The second part is quite easy, but I am struggling with the first regular expression. I used a positive look-behind expression, but it matches only the first comma: `(?<=String\.Concat\(new string\[\] \{[^,}]*),`

I'm not an expert but I think that this is a limitation of the regular expression engine. Once the first comma is matched, the regular expression engine moves the starting matching index after the comma and it doesn't match anymore the look-behind group before it.

---

Is there a regular expression to make this substitution, pluses instead of commas, without the help on any programming language?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: Regexes are search patterns. You cannot make string replacements via regex alone, unless it is in a programming language. What is the environment you are working in?

Comment: No programming language, notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said: first replace all comma by plus signs:

Regex 1: `/,/g`

Replacement 1: `" +"`

Then remove all unnecessary stuff, capture what you need and use a backreference to the captured group as replacement:

Regex 2: `/String\.Concat\(\s*new\s*string\s*\[\]\s*{\s*(.*?)\s*}\)/g`

Replacement 2: `"$1"`(or however you can specify backreferences).

Comment: What if there are some extra spaces in the input? Your should make your substitution(s) more flexible.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the reply, but actually I'm looking to replace only the commas in the curly braces of the String.Concat and not all the commas in the whole document. To replace all the commas in the document I don't need a regular expression, a simple find and replace would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a text editor:

```
,
```

substitution:

```
+
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLG40p/1)

Second:

```
.*?{(.*?)}.*
```

Replacement

```
$1
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLG40p/2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually the document has many other commas, which shouldn't be replaced. I'm looking for a solution to replace only the commas inside the curly braces of the String.Concat.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*  Notepad++ single pass solution
(Note you can also do this in *[RegexFormat8](http://www.regexformat.com)* using the *`Boost extended`* replacement option)

Find `(?:String\.Concat\(\s*new\s*string\s*\[\]\s*{\s*([^,})]*?)\s*(?=,|}\))|\G(?!^)\s*,\s*([^,})]*?)\s*(?=,|}\)))(?:}\)|(?=(?:\s*,\s*[^,})]*)+}\)))`

Replace `(?1$1: + $2)`

(without conditional replace its `+ $1$2` https://regex101.com/r/Vqe44r/1)

Formatted-expand mode

```
 (?:
      String \. Concat\( \s* new \s* string \s* \[\] \s* { \s* 
      ( [^,})]*? )                  # (1)
      \s* 
      (?= , | }\) )
   |  
      \G 
      (?! ^ )
      \s* , \s* 
      ( [^,})]*? )                  # (2)
      \s* 
      (?= , | }\) )

 )

 (?:
      }\) 
   |  
      (?=
           (?:
                \s* , \s* 
                [^,})]* 
           )+
           }\)
      )
 )
```

Output

`"some" + "random" + "text" + string1 + string2 + "end"`

Comment: There is an extra leading `+` in your output

Comment: @Ωmega - I said replacement is up to the user. But, if using Notepad++ something like `(?(1) $1 : + $2)` You'd have to remove the branch reset using this.

Comment: I'll test it in RegexFormat-8 hang on a second.

Comment: @lsn  This is amazing, it works in regex101 but alas not in notepad++. The pattern in regex101 doesn't match and the pattern posted here (which is different) returns "invalid regular expression".

Comment: Is the replacement valid pattern? I have never seen a "conditional" in the replacement pattern. I googled it and I couldn't find anything about it. I have tried it in Notepad++ and Regex101 but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have NP++ so you might have to look at the documentation as to If or what checkbox you need to click to get a _`conditional replacement`_. NP++ uses the boost regex engine for a long time, so there shouldn't be anything different _string wise_. Here is a reference for the syntax boost uses 
https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplaceconditional.html. The conditional is only needed to not add the plus (+) sign on the first group. As far as _my_ regex not working, here is a sample  https://regex101.com/r/dEEJfK/1 works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in two steps.

First substitution

```
s/^\s*String\s*\.Concat\s*\(\s*new\s+string\[\]\s*\{\s*("[^\}]*")\s*\}\)\s*$/$1/i
```

gets you

> "some", "random", "text", string1, string2, "end"

Second one

```
s/\s*("[^"]*"|\b\w+\b)\s*,\s*/$1 + /g
```

returns your desired output

> "some" + "random" + "text" + string1 + string2 + "end"

---

Check this: https://ideone.com/QuRKmt (sample code in Perl).